# Regex to matches multiple string

Tags: regex

need help to separate this string

`value-filter-29[]=Test+1,Test+2,Test+2&+3&value-filter-43[]=Last+30+Days&value-filter-11[]=Testing+number`

into this

- `value-filter-29[]=Test+1,Test+2,Test+2&+3`
- `value-filter-43[]=Last+30+Days`
- `value-filter-11[]=Testing+number`

already tried with regex
`(?:)(value-filter-\d+\[\]=.+?)(&|$)`

and for the first match it will only take `value-filter-29[]=Test+1,Test+2,Test+2` without `&3`

Is there any way to achieve this using regex?

Comment: Which lang are you running?

Comment: im using javascript, i can get the following list by using substring on each value-filter, i dont think it efficient and the code is quite long.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following regex:

```
\&(?=value)
```

It will split at every `&` that is followed by `value`. You can fine-tune this look-ahead later. Looking at the current ouput, you might want to add `-filter-`: `\&(?=value-filter-)`.

See [demo](https://regex101.com/r/nZ3vV9/2)

Output:

```
value-filter-29[]=Test+1,Test+2,Test+2&+3
value-filter-43[]=Last+30+Days
value-filter-11[]=Testing+number
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use a positive lookahead assertion.

```
value-filter-\d+\[\]=.+?(?=&value-filter-|$)
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/nZ3vV9/3)